# I want to know how to got COUNT from SQL in reactjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

my request is good but i want to know how can i use my response in React.

SQL request :

````
    ```
    exports.countAllComments = async (req, res) => {
      const pId = req.params.id;
    
      db.query(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?",
        [pId],
        (err, count) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ err });
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(count)
            res.status(200).json(count);
          }
        }
      );
    };
    ```
````

Front for fetch count:

````
```
    const [countData, setCountData] = useState(0);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCount = async () => {
          try {
            const fetchData = await Axios.get(
              `http://localhost:3001/api/post/comment-count/${post.id}`,
              {
                headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${test1.token}` },
              }
            );
            setCountData(fetchData.data[0]);
          } catch (err) {}
        };
        fetchCount();
      }, [post.id, test1.token]);
    
      console.log(countData);
    ```
````

console log return : "{COUNT(*): 4}" how can i get (4)

Comment: Try this `Object.values(count)[0]`. Or give an alias to `count` and then access that.

Comment: `fetchData.data[0]['COUNT(*)']` ?

Comment: If you change the query to `"SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?"` then it should return "{n: 4}", which should be easier to get the required value from.

Comment: Thanks all for you answers it's working i use: fetchData.data[0]['COUNT(*)'] i need to learn more  js course about array/object lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your trivial example, the trivial solution would be something like -

```
fetchData.data[0]['COUNT(*)']
```

however, you should really have a think about the contract on the API, and enforce a certain return type from your API, and not just simply return the response from the SQL query. i.e. your API could possibly return an object like -

```
{ count: x }
```

where its up to your API to transform the result from the SQL query in a way that satisfies the contract, that way your React client is disconnected from your database layer and only cares about your API contract.

That way your client side becomes something like -

```
fetchData.data.count
```

which wouldn't break if the query where to be updated in some way etc.

Comment: thank you for the answer I would go and review it, it's my first time using COUNT from sql and I was surprised when axios answered : {COUNT(*): 4}